# Предзагрузка (javascript)

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как реализовать предзагрузку (чтоб сайт не загружался пока не загрузятся все картинки).

Нашел вот такое решение но не работает.

```
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;

    });
}

preload([
    'img/1.jpg',
    'img/3.jpg',
    'img/2.jpg'
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    var count_images = arrayOfImages.length;
        count = 0,
        i=0;

    for(i; i < count_images; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = arrayOfImages[i];

        img.onload = function() {
            count++;

            if(count_images-1 == count) {
                alert('картинки загружены');
            }
        }
    }
}

preload([
    'img/1.jpg',
    'img/3.jpg',
    'img/2.jpg'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Может Вам нужно отобразить сайт когда картинки будут готовы?
window.onload будет вызвано ,когда сайт полностью загрузился.Тогда можно показать блок содержащий картинки.
Посмотрите еще эффект lazy-load на jquery.

Comment: "Может Вам нужно отобразить сайт когда картинки будут готовы?" да именно так